# Rodar aplicativo React Native em um iphone com computador Windows

Tags: react, react-native

Boa tarde,
Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de rodar apps desenvolvidos em React Native diretamente no meu aparelho iPhone mas usando o Windows para escrever os códigos.

Comment: Você pode alugar um MAC na nuvem e fazer isso.
Ou criar uma maquina virtual ( mas não fica 100%)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fala meu, é possível sim. Vou responder sua pergunta e falar sobre outras formas de emular o iOS. Uma delas seria alugar um mac na nuvem. Há várias empresas que trabalham nesse seguimento, mas essa https://virtualmacosx.com/ e essa https://www.macincloud.com/ são as principais. Outra maneira é um pouco mais complicada, mas já testei e deu super certo. Outra forma, seria fazer um hackintosh, que nada mais é que rodar um macOS no windows. No youtube há muitos tutoriais com relação ao assunto e caso você tenha interesse, posso passar o link de como fiz o meu. E por último, tem o Expo. Com ele você consegue rodar suas aplicações tanto no Android quanto no iOS. Mas para rodar no iOS, é necessário que você tenha um iPhone. É muito prático, e uma solução muito rápida para seus projetos. Vou deixar esse link para você dar uma olhada em como fazer na prática: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTfaLDDLCqQ

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível executar o comando `react-native run-ios` no Windows, pois, para compilar o código do projeto feito em react native é necessário a ferramenta Xcode que somente funciona no OSX (Sistema operacional da Apple).

Existem algumas soluções no mercado, porém, ou são gambiarras ou são muito lentas.

Atualmente, esta começando a ser muito utilizado o Expo. O Expo permite criar aplicativos para Android e iOS em sua máquina Windows / Linux sem ter que instalar o Xcode ou o Android Studio, usando o Expo SDK e o aplicativo.

Anúncio - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html